# axis2 jar is not available to download anywhere

Tags: apache-axis

From version 1.6.3 to the latest 1.7.4 axis2 jar is not available to download anywhere. I am able to download axis2-kernel-1.6.4.jar, axis2-jaxws-1.6.4.jar etc but not axis2-1.6.4.jar anywhere.

Can someone tell if they have changed the jar name or restructured somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.apache.axis2:axis2` was an all-in-one JAR that [bundled the following Maven artifacts](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/axis/axis2/java/core/tags/v1.6.3/src/main/assembly/jar.xml):

- `org.apache.axis2:axis2-java2wsdl`
- `org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel`
- `org.apache.axis2:axis2-codegen`
- `org.apache.axis2:axis2-adb`
- `org.apache.axis2:axis2-adb-codegen`
- `org.apache.axis2:axis2-xmlbeans`
- `org.apache.axis2:axis2-clustering`
- `org.apache.axis2:addressing`

As explained in the [Axis2 1.6.4 release notes](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/release-notes/1.6.4.html), this all-in-one JAR has been removed from the release. Instead, you should use individual JARs.

Comment: Hi Andreas, org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel
org.apache.axis2:axis2-codegen
org.apache.axis2:axis2-adb were already separate jars not part of org.apache.axis2:axis2. There is no documentation which can tell the exact jars which were part of bundled org.apache.axis2:axis2.

Comment: These JARs have always existed as separate JARs. It's just that org.apache.axis2:axis2 aggregated them into a single JAR, and the ones you mention were part of that aggregation. I've added a link to the build definition.

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks a ton.